# Joining on Is Null MS Access SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access

How do I join 2 tables in MS Access that may have NULL values in the join fields?  For instance I have 2 tables, Table1 and Table2.  I would like to join them on Table1.[Test Field 1] = Table2.[Test Field 1].  Also if the field in both tables is NULL I would like them to join.  I have tried a couple different ways of going about this, including the SQL below.  When I try to run that I get the error message: "Missing ),], or Item in Query expression..."  I've tried inserting more brackets etc but nothing has worked.

```
SELECT Table1.[Test Field 1], Table1.[Test Field 2], Table2.[Test Field 1], Table2.[Test Field 2]
FROM Table1 INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table1.[Test Field 1] = Table2.[Test Field 1] 
OR (ISNULL(table1.[test field 1]) AND ISNULL(table2.[Test Field 1]));
```

Answer (score 3):

Any `ON` clause in Access with more than 1 comparison needs to be wrapped in parentheses. Unfortunately, the error message you got is not very descriptive, but it's easy to fix.

```
SELECT Table1.[Test Field 1], Table1.[Test Field 2], Table2.[Test Field 1], Table2.[Test Field 2]
FROM Table1 INNER JOIN Table2 ON (Table1.[Test Field 1] = Table2.[Test Field 1] 
OR (ISNULL(table1.[test field 1]) AND ISNULL(table2.[Test Field 1])));
```

Answer (score 0):

`IS NULL` with a space checks if a column is actually null.  This may be what you're looking to use.  Here is your query using `IS NULL` after the column names:

```
SELECT Table1.[Test Field 1], Table1.[Test Field 2], Table2.[Test Field 1], Table2.[Test Field 2]
FROM Table1
INNER JOIN Table2 ON (Table1.[Test Field 1] = Table2.[Test Field 1] 
   OR (table1.[test field 1] IS NULL AND table2.[Test Field 1] IS NULL));
```

Comment: This is Access JET/Ace SQL. `ISNULL` takes one parameter, and returns `True` if `Null`, else `False`, exactly the same as `Field Is Null`. In T-SQL you would be right. The equivalent of T-SQLs `ISNULL` is `Nz` in JET/Ace SQL.

Comment: Good point, I've updated this answer to show IS NULL as an option and removed the faulty information.

Comment: @danjuggler, since this question is about MS Access, it needs to be `ISNULL(field)`, not `field IS NULL` as you still have here in 2023.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is using the Nz-Function in the **join**. Nz substitutes **NULL** with the second item

```
JOIN 
ON    …
AND  (Nz([Tab1].[MayBeNULL_Field],"SubstitutingValue") 
   =  Nz([Tab2].[MayBeNULL_Field],"SubstitutingValue")
     )
```